# Getting an error while creating new instance SQLITE

Tags: java, android, sqlite, instance

i have an error while making a creating a new instance for writing data to my database SQLlite

this is the code of my database class

```
    package com.example.tttt;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class info {

    public static final String key_nom = "nom_personne";
    public static final String key_id = "id_personne";
    public static final String key_prenom = "prenom_personne";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "infodb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "infotable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1 ;
    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private Context ourContext ;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase ;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null , DATABASE_VERSION );
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        key_id  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        key_nom + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        key_prenom + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }


}
public info open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
    public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}
    public long createEntry(String name, String prenom) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(key_nom, name);
        cv.put(key_prenom, prenom);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

in my class activity i wrote

```
 info entry = new info(this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name , prenom );
            entry.close();
```

i had a error on     `info entry = new info(this);` 
the message error : " The constructor info(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined "

when i change to info `entry = new info(intro.this);`

i got: "The constructor info(intro) is undefined"

the full intro activity where i try get information from the user and send them to the database

```
package com.example.tttt;

import com.example.tttt.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.DropBoxManager.Entry;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class intro extends Activity  {
Button sqlupdate,sqlview,sqlsearch;
EditText sqlnom, sqlprenom,sqltextsearch ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.intro);
      sqlnom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nomenter);
      sqlprenom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.prenomenter);
      sqlupdate =        (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      sqlview =        (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //  sqlsearch =        (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
   //   sqltextsearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


      sqlupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean diditwork = true ;

            try{
            String name = sqlnom.getText().toString();
            String prenom = sqlprenom.getText().toString(); 

            entry = new info();
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name , prenom );
        entry.close();

            }catch (Exception e ){

          diditwork = false ;
          String error = e.toString();
          Dialog d = new Dialog(intro.this); 
            d.setTitle(" merde ");
            TextView tv = new TextView(intro.this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
            }finally{
         if (diditwork){
            Dialog d = new Dialog(intro.this); 
            d.setTitle(" okkk ");
            TextView tv = new TextView(intro.this);
            tv.setText(" ok yes ");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
         }

            }
        }


    });
      sqlview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent open = new Intent("android.intent.action.SQLVIEW");
            startActivity(open);
        }



    });


    sqlsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     /*String s = sqltextsearch.getText().toString();

            info se = new info();
            se.open();
            String returne = se.search();
       */     




        }
    });


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialize the info class without parameters:

```
info entry = new info();
```

btw. It is common in class names to write the first letter uppercase: `Info`

Furthermore. If you dont have more code in `info` your application will throw a `NullPointerException` here `ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);`

Comment: thanks for the quick answer when i use entry=new info(); i got i error : entry cannot be resolved to a variable   if i use info entry = new info(); i got no error but writing in database don't work

Comment: you should start with a tutorial. the class you got do nothing with any database.

Comment: name and prenom are not null?

Comment: String name = sqlnom.getText().toString();
  String prenom = sqlprenom.getText().toString();  in intro activity updated post

Answer (score 0):

Here in the Class **Info** there is no **Constructor** with an Argument of type **Intro**

Create one if you really need to have the instance of the class Intro at Class Info.

```
public Info(Intro intro){
    }
```

Else Create a Constructor without any argument passed.

```
 Info entry = new Info(this);
```

Always try to follow the naming Conventions, its not a good way to program in any way you like. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: hi Dillep thanks for the answer  whene i add a constructor with an argument  in info class my app crash !! in SQLite tutorial they did not add any constructor and the instance is fine i don't know i'm really confused now

Comment: @user2686117 Every time when you initialize an object of a class, it calls the constructor of the class. Even if you wont create a constructor inside, by default a constructor without any argument is created and its called when the Object initialization takes place. 
Here it generates error because there is no class constructor with an argument of type Intro. 
Post the error you get when u initialize without passing any argument

Comment: hi i upload image error   http://i1257.photobucket.com/albums/ii518/yassinema1992/error_zps3f8afe7c.png

Comment: @user2686117 Did u created a constructor with the argument Intro inside Class info.?? public info(Intro ObjName){;}